# PHPMAILER Not sending and not giving error

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am trying to let users fill out a contact form, which will then be sent to my email. But its not working for some reason. I just get a blank page with no error message or any text and email is also not sent.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    include_once('class.phpmailer.php');

    $name = strip_tags($_POST['full_name']);
    $email = strip_tags ($_POST['email']);
    $msg = strip_tags ($_POST['description']);

    $subject = "Contact Form from DigitDevs Website";

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    $mail->Host       = "mail.example.com"; // SMTP server example
    //$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username   = "info@example.com"; // SMTP account username example
    $mail->Password   = "password";        // SMTP account password example

    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->FromName = $name;

    $mail->AddAddress('info@example.com', 'Information'); 
    $mail->AddReplyTo($email, 'Wale');

    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = $subject;

    $mail->Body    =  $msg;
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
}
echo 'Message has been sent';
```

Comment: Check the server logs and find out what's wrong.

Comment: which os your using ?In case of `Ubuntu` if mail sending fails then in your web root a file named `dead.letter` will be created,once check that.

Comment: Try to insert '}' after 'exit;'

Comment: or after last 'echo' ?

Comment: @AmalMurali this is what i get in the log:           [28-Jun-2013 11:57:02 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required 'class.smtp.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/digitdev/public_html/class.phpmailer.php on line 1004

Comment: @Wale: Did you follow the directions in the INSTALL.txt file, including downloading and installing the PHPMailer package?

Comment: Are you using Gmail?

Answer (score 17):

You need to call:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // with true in the parenthesis
```

From the documentation:

> The `true` param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need
>   to catch.

Comment: You, sir, are a real hero! I have been fighting a bug for a while, but was unable to locate it, until now!

Answer (score 15):

Its working now, i didnt include the 'class.smtp.php' file. The working code is below:

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 include_once('class.phpmailer.php');

 require_once('class.smtp.php');

$name = strip_tags($_POST['full_name']);
$email = strip_tags ($_POST['email']);
$msg = strip_tags ($_POST['description']);

$subject = "Contact Form from DigitDevs Website";

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->Host       = "mail.example.com"; // SMTP server example
//$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "info@example.com"; // SMTP account username example
$mail->Password   = "password";        // SMTP account password example

$mail->From = $email;
$mail->FromName = $name;

$mail->AddAddress('info@example.com', 'Information'); 
$mail->AddReplyTo($email, 'Wale');

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $subject;

$mail->Body    =  $msg;
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}
 echo 'Message has been sent';
```

Comment: This CORRECT. I had the same issue , after adding the class.smtp.php it work fine.

Comment: Also requiring `SMTP.php` was vital for me, too.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem with no error message even with SMTPDebug enabled. After searching around for working examples I noticed that I didn't include the **SMTP Secure** value. Try adding this line:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; //secure transfer enabled
```

Work like a charm now.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. In reference to @Syclone's answer. I was using the default "tls".

`$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`

After I changed it to 
    `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';` 
It worked ! My mailserver was only accepting connections over SSL.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was setting From as Username and FromName as $_POST['email']

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

PHPMailer use exception.

Try this

```
try {

    include_once('class.phpmailer.php');

    $name = strip_tags($_POST['full_name']);
    $email = strip_tags ($_POST['email']);
    $msg = strip_tags ($_POST['description']);

    $subject = "Contact Form from DigitDevs Website";

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    $mail->Host       = "mail.example.com"; // SMTP server example
    //$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username   = "info@example.com"; // SMTP account username example
    $mail->Password   = "password";        // SMTP account password example

    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->FromName = $name;

    $mail->AddAddress('info@example.com', 'Information'); 
    $mail->AddReplyTo($email, 'Wale');

    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = $subject;

    $mail->Body    =  $msg;
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->Send();

    exit;

} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Dreamweaver highlights the code from "catch" as red which means syntax is not correct...

Comment: I tested the code with php balise "<?php // your code ?>". It does not have parse error.

Comment: just tried it again and no code error, but it still doent work. Will my error_log help?

Comment: your email is no sent or no received ? without error your email is probably no received

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to load an HTML file to send, which did not belong to the www-data group on my Ubuntu server.

```
chown -R www-data * 
chgrp -R www-data *
```

Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I was debating whether to write my own handler or crow-bar PHPMailer into my existing class structure. In the event it was very easy because of the versatility of the spl_autoload_register function which is used within the PHPMailer system as well as my existing class structure.

I simply created a basic class Email in my existing class structure as follows

```
<?php

   /**
     * Provides link to PHPMailer
     *
     * @author Mike Bruce
     */
   class Email {
      public $_mailer; // Define additional class variables as required by your application
      public function __construct()
      {
         require_once "PHPMail/PHPMailerAutoload.php" ;
         $this->_mailer = new PHPMailer() ;
         $this->_mailer->isHTML(true);
         return $this;
      }
   }
?>
```

From a calling Object class the code would be:

```
$email = new Email;
$email->_mailer->functionCalls();

// continue with more function calls as required
```

Works a treat and has saved me re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ssl settings:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure  = 'tls'; //tls or ssl
$mail->SMTPOptions = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer'       => false,
                                          'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                                          'allow_self_signed' => true));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try with the following sample code.**

```php
<?php
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.example.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'user@example.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'secret';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     //Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               //Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

   
    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

**Use a free SMTP sandbox like [MailMug.net](https://mailmug.net/count) account to test it**