# I'm not abble to send e-mail with HTML form and PHPMailer

Tags: php, html, email

I'm trying to send an e-mail through an html form with attachment. The problem is that  with the code that I'm putting next, the form isn't sending any e-mail...

Can anyone help me??

I rally need this to work and I´m getting desperate because I've trying a lot of stuff and I'm not getting the solution.

The code:

```
      <!-- Formulário RH -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h1>Recrutamento</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <br />
            <p>Se gostava de trabalhar connosco envie-nos a sua candidatura preenchendo este formulário.</p>
            <br />
            <form id="form-contacto" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="?acao=enviar">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                            <p class="text-top-rh">Que tipo de candidatura quer fazer?</p>
                  <div class="checkbox" style="text-align: left">
                    <input class="form-control" name="cand" placeholder="Ex: Colaborador Interno ou Perito Externo" type="text" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" type="text" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" type="email" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" name="tel" placeholder="Número de telefone" type="number">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" name="pai" placeholder="PAI/20XX/XXXX" type="text">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" name="zona_resid" placeholder="Zona de Residência" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" name="zona_act" placeholder="Zona de Actuação" type="text">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                  <textarea class="form-control" name="mensagem" placeholder="Apresentação" type="text" rows="5"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group"  style="text-align: left">
                  <label>Anexar Curriculum vitae:</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                  <input name="arquivo" type="file" class="form-control-file">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          <div class="panel-footer">
            <h3>Envie a sua candidatura</h3>
            <input class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" name="btn_enviar" value="Enviar"></input>
          </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    if($_GET['acao'] == 'enviar'){
     $cand        = $_POST['cand'];
     $nome        = $_POST['nome'];
     $email       = $_POST['email'];
     $tel         = $_POST['tel'];
     $pai         = $_POST['pai'];
     $zona_resid  = $_POST['zona_resid'];
     $zona_act    = $_POST['zona_act'];
     $assunto     = "Candidatura enviada a partir de Brick.pt";
     $arquivo     = $_FILES["arquivo"];

     $corpoMSG = "<strong>Candidatura para:</strong> $cand<br>
                  <br />
                  <strong>Nome:</strong> $nome<br>
                  <br />
                  <strong>E-mail:</strong> $mail<br>
                  <br />
                  <strong>Telefone:</strong> $tel<br>
                  <br />
                  <strong>PAI:</strong> $pai<br>
                  <br />
                  <strong>Zona de Residência:</strong> $zona_resid<br>
                  <br />
                  <strong>Zona  de Atuação:</strong> $zona_act<br>";
     // chamada da classe
     require 'php/src/Exception.php';
     require 'php/src/PHPMailer.php';
     require 'php/src/SMTP.php';
     require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');
     // instanciando a classe
     $mail   = new PHPMailer();
     // email do remetente
     $mail->SetFrom('$email', 'remetente');
     // email do destinatario
     $address = "julianasameiro@gmail.com";
     $mail->AddAddress($address, "destinatario");
     // assunto da mensagem
     $mail->Subject = $assunto;
     // corpo da mensagem
     $mail->MsgHTML($corpoMSG);
     // anexar arquivo
     $mail->AddAttachment($arquivo['tmp_name'], $arquivo['name']  );

     if(!$mail->Send()) {
       echo "Erro: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
      } else {
       echo "Mensagem enviada com sucesso!";
      }
    }

?>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Is there some error messsage you get ?

Comment: any messages on the error logs?

Comment: No, it doesn't appear any message or error, just don't sends the e-mail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMAILER Not sending and not giving error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364323/phpmailer-not-sending-and-not-giving-error)

Comment: What does the condition `!$mail->Send()` returns ? The message saying success ?

Comment: since you are using Gmail. Did you put the gmail smtp server and port?

Comment: ($_GET['acao'] == 'enviar') never gets true, assuming that this is whole script.

Comment: @SaadIsmail - $_GET['acao']=='enviar' when the user hits 'submit' button. This is because of the action="?acao=enviar">. This sets the variable 'acao' to 'enviar' in the $_GET array on submit.